# GTP support in OpenFlow

Tags: network-core, tunnel, sdn, openflow

I know there is a "tunnel id" metadata matching field which was introduced in the 1.3 openflow release, if I'm not mistaken. However, are there any actions in supporting the encapsulation and decapsulation process of a tunnel protocol, like GTP? I suppose there are, as the tunnel metadata is present in the openflow matching implementation, so in this case what are the specific encap/decap actions, in order to apply therefore the routing decisions on the actual tunneled ip packet?